# How to sort a vector based on a list in R

Tags: r, sorting, vector

For example, I have the vector

```
x=c(-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,1,-1,1).
```

And the following list:

```
Y =
list(1:7, 8:11, 12:15, 16:19)
```

How to sort the vector `x` based on list `Y`? I mean to sort the first 7 elements, the next 4, the next 4 and the last 4 AT THE SAME TIME.

The desired output should be
    `c(-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1)`.

Note that list `Y` is not always the same.

I tried to use `x[unlist(sapply(Y, sort))]`, but it does not work.

Do you have any option?

Comment: Can you paste your expected output?

Comment: And please add your `Y` object in a copy/pasteable way. `dput(Y)` will do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
unlist(lapply(lapply(Y, function(i) x[i]), sort))
# [1] -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1 -1 -1  1  1 -1 -1  1  1 -1 -1  1  1
```

This first extracts the elements of `x` according to the indices in `Y` into different list items, with

```
lapply(Y, function(i) x[i])
```

then it sorts each one independently with `lapply(..., sort)`, then recombines them back into a vector with `unlist`.

---

Using this input:

```
x = c(-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,1,-1,1)
Y = list(1:7, 8:11, 12:15, 16:19)
```

Comment: Or `ave(x, stack(setNames(Y, seq_along(Y)))$ind, FUN = sort)` or maybe `x[order(stack(setNames(Y, seq_along(Y)))$ind, x)]`

Answer (score 3):

Not sure this is want you're asking for

```
> unlist(lapply(y, function(z) sort(x[z])))
 [1] -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1 -1 -1  1  1 -1 -1  1  1 -1 -1  1  1
```

Inputs

```
x <- c(-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,1,-1,1)
y <- list(1:7, 8:11, 12:15, 16:19)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also avoid a loop and vectorize the order using both `x` and `Y` at the same time (because `order` allows ordering by two vectors in case of ties)

```
x[order(rep(seq_along(Y), lengths(Y)), x)]
# [1] -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1 -1 -1  1  1 -1 -1  1  1 -1 -1  1  1
```

---

Some benchmark for illustration

```
set.seed(123)
N <- 1e5
x <- sample(N) 
Y <- split(1:N, rep(1 : (N/5), each = 5))


microbenchmark::microbenchmark("Gregor" = unlist(lapply(lapply(Y, function(i) x[i]), sort)),
                               "Frank1" = ave(x, stack(setNames(Y, seq_along(Y)))$ind, FUN = sort),
                               "Frank2" = x[order(stack(setNames(Y, seq_along(Y)))$ind, x)],
                               "Jilber" =  unlist(lapply(Y, function(z) sort(x[z]))),
                               "David" = x[order(rep(seq_along(Y), lengths(Y)), x)])


# Unit: milliseconds
#   expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq         max neval cld
# Gregor 904.277546 937.652137 958.911977 949.311012 961.324917 1164.024555   100   c
# Frank1 884.306262 922.496558 956.408754 941.394433 962.098976 1140.254656   100   c
# Frank2  27.384839  28.587845  30.806481  29.542219  31.684239   46.947814   100  b 
# Jilber 923.135901 949.318532 967.981792 962.090176 976.574574 1137.115863   100   c
# David   2.184901   2.326817   2.622338   2.492732   2.524091    8.586322   100 a
```

Vectorized solution ~X500 faster than a loop

Comment: I'm very surprised my answer beats Jilber's, even if it's only by a hair. I saw Jilber's method and thought *"I should have done it that way"*. I suppose it's not worth worrying about when your answer is 500x faster than either.